# ✓ Checkmark Character Encoding Issue In WordPress Editor

Tags: visual-editor, encoding

While writing a new blog post on my WordPress blog, I noticed that it is converting '✓' (checkmark) to '?' (question mark). I am using the classic editor (not the block one).

I tried to enter the ✓ character in multiple ways like using the `&check;` HTML entity also but as soon as I moved to the visual tab on the editor the character changed back to ?.

I read somewhere that commenting the following lines in wp-config.php fixes this issue.

```
//define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
//define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

In my case committing these two lines fixed the issue for this very blog post but all the older posts seem to be messed up.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using UTF8? What's the default if you do turn that off?

Comment: How is the checkmark saved in the old posts in the database? As a ?, or as a UTF-8 sequence, or some other character?